# Different subnet masks

Tags: networking, subnet

Let's assume simple topology.

```
PC-1 <-------> PC-2

PC-1: 192.168.0.1/24
PC-2: 192.168.0.129/25
```

No switches, no routers, just two PCs with static configuration.

From PC-1 perspective PC-2 should be reachable, but from PC-2 communication should not work. Is it correct? If so, is it used somewhere in practice?

Comment: yes, that is correct, though there are a few nuances. no this is not generally a desirable configuration you would find in the real world. First off, there wouldn't really be communication between either node, since #2 can't respond. also I believe you could place a route on #2 that would allow communication, since both systems are actually on the shared lan. the mask when configured on an endpoint, will tell that endpoint how the network is configured, and when to engage a router to cross network boundaries.  So yeah, you do understand, and no no one would do this under normal circumstances.

Comment: Things to make it not work from PC1 to PC2 when enabled: [2.2. Strict Reverse Path Forwarding](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3704#section-2.2 "RFC 3704"). This can affect ARP too depending on the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you present there, is a broken IP configuration. The host could exchange messages at layer 2, but IP connectivity is not possible between the hosts. Note that if your #2 host fell in the range 192.168.0.2-127, there would be no issue.
As a general rule, all endpoints in your subnetwork should have consistent masks, though as you can see, there is potentially some wiggle room.

So first off, an IP subnet is just a plain old network (albeit a smaller one). That you carved it out of a larger network is really unimportant in most regards. Just like any network, it will have an Identity (the first address in the range), a range of addresses, and a broadcast address (the last address in the range).  In order to send traffic to another network, the traffic must pass through a router. This is true even if the two networks are subnet of a single larger network.

There are usecases where IP addresses are assigned a mask that combines multiple subnets, but these generally occur in routing tables inside routers that connect those networks, or more usefully, routers that connect to your routers several steps upstream. this is called route aggregation or supernetting, and its a useful trick, but only in routers. you would only care about it if you were managing a large number of networks.

Comment: Is a comment made by @anikranak correct?

Comment: I'm sure that historically there is at least one application that has used UDP to send datagrams one way, unsolicited, but I cannot think of one at present. All the common UDP applications I can think of require at least one request and one response, but I'm sure there has been one.

Comment: Ok, I got it. But theoretically such one-way traffic is possible?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I'm not sure. it may vary by IP stack. I am sure that reachability exists from 1 -> 2 (and not the reverse), but I'm not actually certain that the packet won't be ignored as illegal. The IP 192.168.0.1 is a network identity if the subnet mask is anything greater than /24, and network identities are not allowed as a source IP in a packet. network Identities are used only in routing tables and other aggregations like multicast (I think). they are not legitimate for unicast traffic.

Comment: Ignored? Why? I thought that from PC-2 perspective it would be the same as getting a packet from a router. Unless the sender IP is replaced by router as well, for instance because of NAT.

Comment: because 192.168.0.1 is not a valid address from #2's perspective.  #1 believes its address is valid (because it is) but to #2, that is a network id so its not a valid source or destination address. if you used 192.168.0.2 though, that would probably work.

Comment: So does it mean that router is delivering incoming datagrams from outer networks with it's own IP as a source?

Comment: needless to say, things get really complicated when subnet masks are used inconsistently within their internetwork. you start getting into edge cases, or cases where windows handles it differently than unix or whatever.

Comment: No not at all. there is no router in this equation. its simply that when you configured station #2, you told it that that its mask is /25. It then calculates the ID, the range, and the broadcast address for that address in a /25 network, and in a /25 network, 192.168.0.1 is not a valid endpoint address.

Comment: I am asking more in general, because you mentioned that datagrams from different subnets may be treated as invalid, so I am thinking how casual home routers deliver datagrams from the outernetworks and whether they are using their own IP as a source.

Comment: the issue here is that since #2 has a mask of /25, it expects the other stations on that network to be similarly configured.  Note that a home router cannot have 192.168.0.x on its inside, and also on its outside, so it knows that there is an overlap. besides, in this example, an assumption of no routers is explicitly stated. things get more complicated if there were a router, and #2 had a route to 192.168.0.1/25.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that one way UDP datagrams should work well from PC-1 to PC-2. As TCP requires duplex, it would not work.