# Different subnet masks on same network

Tags: networking, home-networking, subnet

I have a home network which is currently setup to use the `192.168.1.0 / 255.255.255.0` IP subnet. with my ISPs router `192.168.1.254` as default gateway.

I'd like to add some IP cameras to the same network but with two restrictions:

1. They should not be able to connect to the internet.
2. They should be browsable by at least some of the computers on my network.

I am aware that one way to do this would be to have three vlans but as it stands, I am not able to connect them as such, because that would require a major rewiring.

Therefore I see three possible scenarios:

1. Give them fixed IPs in a completely different subnet (`10.0.0.0 / 255.0.0.0` or `192.168.2.0 / 255.255.255.0`) and configure the PCs that I want to be able to browse these cameras a virtual IP in the same network (I have a couple of linux servers with this kind of setup already).
   My issue with this approach is that windows clients are not as easy to provide a secondary IP address as linux clients are when you are using dhcp.
   [image]
2. Give them an IP address in the subnet `192.168.2.0 / 255.255.0.0` and modify the subnet masks of the PCs that should be able to contact them to `255.255.0.0`.
   I can read from [Different subnet masks](https://superuser.com/questions/1658172/different-subnet-masks) that this approach is not a good one.
3. Give them fixed IPs in a completely different subnet (`10.0.0.0 / 255.0.0.0`) and set up one of my linux servers to route traffic to that subnet from certain machines.

If I choose option 3, how do I configure my windows PCs to route traffic to 10.0.0.0 through my server at 192.168.1.241 ?

I cannot change the configuration of My ISPs router to add routing information to the DHCP service.

[image]

Comment: And your ISPs router doesn't allow blocking/allowing access to the internet via client's MAC addresses either?  -  Another option would be to configure the IP cams with static IPs in your normal subnet but without setting 192.168.1.254 as the gateway (or just setting no gateway at all).  ->  All devices on your LAN can talk to each other, only the IP cams cant connect to the internet because they don't "know" any route to it.

Comment: What about giving them fixed addresses in the same subnet, but incorrect router and DNS server addresses (maybe their own addresses if they allow it)? That should prevent them from reaching the outside world.

Comment: @GordonDavisson good suggestion, and in some other situation i might use an approach like that, but part of the goal is also to not allow all machines on my net to browse these clients, which this does not prevent

Comment: @GordonDavisson - I already suggested that in the comment above... (AT)JoSSte - I don'T know about your specific setup but I'd most likely just use a cheap (<5€) oWRT router like the "o2 box 6431" to either firewall+route just the IP cams or firewall your whole network (network <-> oWRT <-> ISP-crap-router). There are probably >half-a-dozen different specific configuration types for those two options.

Comment: @Limer I am looking to swith in my own router at some point in the future, and then I will be able to make the setup much more robust. I had  my Linksys WRT 1900ACS  as my previous router but its WAN port suddenly would only connect at 100Mbps so now it is only an access point and switch. Its  LAN ports are operating at the expected 1gbps

Comment: @JoSSte - that would be the simplest solution but you already have an oWRT router with [VLAN](https://openwrt.org/toh/linksys/wrt1900acs#switch_ports_for_vlans) (I think). -> Two more options: - 1. try setting its WAN port to a fixed 1Gbps (mybe just the auto negotiation is borked). - 2. Disable DHCP in your ISPs router and use the WRT1900ACS for that (not as a router for the network, just DHCP with a static route to itself for the IP cams + global/0.0.0.0 route to the ISP router).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am aware that one way to do this would be to have three vlans but as it stands, I am not able to connect them as such, because that would require a major rewiring.

Usually the point of vlans is to *not* require major rewiring, only new equipment at the end of the existing wiring. You can have a single cable carrying multiple "tagged" VLANs, with switches on each end splitting it up into dedicated ports.

> 3. Give them fixed IPs in a completely different subnet (10.0.0.0 / 255.0.0.0) and set up one of my linux servers to route traffic to that subnet from certain machines.
>
> If I choose option 3, how do I configure my windows PCs to route traffic to 10.0.0.0 through my server at 192.168.1.241 ?

Through the CLI:

- `route -p add 10.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.241`
- `New-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 10.0.0.0/8 -NextHop 192.168.1.241`

`-p` makes the route persistent across reboots.

(I would recommend using smaller *subnets* than /8; it will make things easier when you want a second one, and a third. Start with 10.0.0.0/16 or similar – then if you decide you want another subnet you'll be able to just use 10.1.0.0/16 and so on. All of them can still take the single 10.0.0.0/8 route, of course.)

Comment: Excellent answer. This is a home network with two 8-port switches and two routers acting as accesspoints. only one switch is managed, so rewiring for vlans will require new equipment and a LOT of extra wire runs. I have considered if openWRT could make VLANS based on the MACS for me (virtually)

Comment: It does need new equipment, but why would it need extra wire runs?

Comment: @JoSSte if you can connect all IP cams directly to the managed switch all you need is configure 2 VLANs and you're done. No rewiring at all.  And what do you mean with "VLANs based on MACs"?! AFAIK that makes no sense. Do you mean an oWRT device using an un-tagged port to receive IP packets and deciding on the senders MAC in which VLAN to put it? Pretty sure that is not a scenario how VLANs can be used / are supposed to work.

Comment: @Limer: It's not a _usual_ scenario how VLANs are used, but it's not impossible; switch chips have a fair bit of programmability for tricks beyond 802.1Q tagging. For example, something very similar is done when 802.1X authentication is involved (the Ethernet equivalent of WPA-Enterprise) – instead of it being port-level as originally designed, many new switches can remember which individual client MACs are authenticated... and which VLANs they got assigned to. _Still,_ however, this needs to be done at switch level, not at router level, so it needs new equipment either way.

Comment: @u1686_grawity - sure, it might be technically possible but receiving/transmitting untagged Ethernet frames for different VLANs on the same physical port at the same time sound like a disaster waiting to happen. I know about 802.1X but doesn't that at most switch between different VLANs = never two untagged at the same time?

Comment: @u1686_grawity i updated my querstion with a topolgy map indicating how the wires are run, and how I foresee the cables having to run if i only use 1 vlan. the connection between the two buildings is not easily accessed and will most likely also require repainting two walls If it goes as badly as the first time 

Comment: @JoSSte: I don't see a problem there. The existing "red" cable between two buildings can easily carry all of the VLANs at once; the existing LAN becoming a 'VLAN' as well. (That's literally the whole point of 802.1Q VLANs – the "tagging" done by switches is what allows them to share a single cable while staying isolated. Running two separate cables wouldn't be "VLANs", just…LANs.) Though they'll need to share the bandwidth of a single 1Gbps physical link, but usually that's not a problem, not unless you have a whole lot of 4K cameras.

Comment: @u1686_grawity i thought that everything on thatcable including the accesspoint, the PCs that connect to that and the server beyond would end up on the camera vlan?

Comment: @JoSSte: No, the whole idea is that it wouldn't be limited to only that. Between buildings it would have multiple tagged VLANs, and _on each end_ you'd have a switch that splits it up into individual "normal" ports (aka access or untagged ports); you'd decide which Ethernet ports are on the "main" VLAN and which are on the "camera" VLAN. (The linux server that does routing could be set up on a tagged multi-VLAN port as well.)

Comment: @JoSSte - u1686_grawity is right and if you can put your managed switch in one building and the WRT1900ACS in the other you should already have everything you need. As in: switch+router transmitting VLAN tagged Ethernet between each other over the one existing cable **while simultaneously** presenting as two different networks to the other connected devices - you decide which port belongs into which VLAN **or** even both VLANs _forwarded_ on the same port to eg. the linux servers which/who(?) usually can be configured to use VLANs directly themselves (one virtual NIC per VLAN).

Answer (score 2):

Setting second network is for me the simplest way. I do not know why you thing in Windows is so hard to set. Here is the screen:

[image: advanced TCP/IP settings]

Comment: I found the settings you refer to. that may be the easiest way forward

Comment: How does this enable @JoSSte to add a different static IP when he's using DHCP?!  -  
Windows doesn't allow that (at least not between win2k and 8.1).  -  
You can either use DHCP exclusive_or multiple static IPs.

Comment: @Limer I have two different PCs i use one with a static IP and one with a static lease (since the rest of my household are using DHCP, having a pc to test with is relevant.) I can live with having to use a linux PC or my static IP PC to access the cameras...